# How to create a heatmap with marginal histograms, similar to a jointplot?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I want to plot 2-dimensional scalar data, which I would usually plot using `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` or `sns.heatmap`. Consider this example:

```py
data = [[10, 20, 30], [50, 50, 100], [80, 60, 10]]
fix, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data, cmap=plt.cm.YlGn)
```

[image: 3x3 imshow plot]

Now I additionally would like to have one-dimonsional bar plots at the top and the right side, showing the sum of the values in each column / row - just as `sns.jointplot` does. However, `sns.jointplot` seems only to work with categorical data, producing histograms (with `kind='hist'`), scatterplots or the like - I don't see how to use it if I want to specify the values of the cells directly. Is such a thing possible with seaborn?

The `y` axis in my plot is going to be days (within a month), the `x` axis is going to be hours. My data looks like this:

[image: DataFrame with hour, day and values]

The field `Cost Difference` is what should make up the shade of the respective field in the plot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an approach that first creates a dummy `jointplot` and then uses its axes to add a heatmap and bar plots of the sums.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

D = 28
H = 24
df = pd.DataFrame({'day': np.repeat(range(1, D + 1), H),
                   'hour': np.tile(range(H), D),
                   'Cost Dif.': np.random.uniform(10, 1000, D * H)})
# change the random df to have some rows/columns stand out (debugging, checking)
df.loc[df['hour'] == 10, 'Cost Dif.'] = 150
df.loc[df['hour'] == 12, 'Cost Dif.'] = 250
df.loc[df['day'] == 20, 'Cost Dif.'] = 800

g = sns.jointplot(data=df, x='day', y='hour', kind='hist', bins=(D, H))
g.ax_marg_y.cla()
g.ax_marg_x.cla()
sns.heatmap(data=df['Cost Dif.'].to_numpy().reshape(D, H).T, ax=g.ax_joint, cbar=False, cmap='Blues')

g.ax_marg_y.barh(np.arange(0.5, H), df.groupby(['hour'])['Cost Dif.'].sum().to_numpy(), color='navy')
g.ax_marg_x.bar(np.arange(0.5, D), df.groupby(['day'])['Cost Dif.'].sum().to_numpy(), color='navy')

g.ax_joint.set_xticks(np.arange(0.5, D))
g.ax_joint.set_xticklabels(range(1, D + 1), rotation=0)
g.ax_joint.set_yticks(np.arange(0.5, H))
g.ax_joint.set_yticklabels(range(H), rotation=0)

# remove ticks between heatmao and histograms
g.ax_marg_x.tick_params(axis='x', bottom=False, labelbottom=False)
g.ax_marg_y.tick_params(axis='y', left=False, labelleft=False)
# remove ticks showing the heights of the histograms
g.ax_marg_x.tick_params(axis='y', left=False, labelleft=False)
g.ax_marg_y.tick_params(axis='x', bottom=False, labelbottom=False)

g.fig.set_size_inches(20, 8)  # jointplot creates its own figure, the size can only be changed afterwards
# g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.3) # optionally more space for the tick labels
g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.05, wspace=0.02)  # less spaced needed when there are no tick labels
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. One more question though: I would like to have ticks only on the big heatmap, not on the barplots on the side/top. I tried calling `.set_ticks([])` on various parts of the plot (`g.ax_marg_x`, `g.ax_marg_y`), but I only manage to switch off *all* ticks.

Comment: `g.ax_marg_x.tick_params(axis='x', bottom=False, labelbottom=False)` and `g.ax_marg_y.tick_params(axis='y', left=False, labelleft=False)` removes the labels between the heatmap and the histograms.  Doing the same with `ax_marg_x` and `ax_marg_y` reversed would also remove the ticks indicating the heights.

Comment: I updated the answer to remove the ticks on the marginal plots. Now there is room to remove some whitespace between the subplots.